# Json.NET to GSON, probably newbie issue

Tags: json, json.net

I have an app in .NET that I want to be able to talk to an Android app. Some research suggested not using XML, my usual choice, but instead using JSON which I've never touched. I'm using Json.NET and GSON.

I have a simple class in .NET;

```
public enum eCommandType
{
    UNKNOWN,
    PING,
    GET_TIMINGS,
    GET_EVENT_ID,
    NEW_EVENT,
    LOAD_PEOPLE,
    LOAD_TAGS,
    SET_LOCATION
}

public class CommandBase
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public eCommandType CommandType { get; set; }
}
```

I generate a schema using

```
        //Encode enums as strings, not integers.
        JSchemaGenerator stringEnumGenerator = new JSchemaGenerator();
        stringEnumGenerator.GenerationProviders.Add
            (new StringEnumGenerationProvider());

        JSchema schema = stringEnumGenerator.Generate(typeof(CommandBase));
        string s = schema.ToString();
```

That schema is

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "CommandType": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "UNKNOWN",
        "PING",
        "GET_TIMINGS",
        "GET_EVENT_ID",
        "NEW_EVENT",
        "LOAD_PEOPLE",
        "LOAD_TAGS",
        "SET_LOCATION"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "CommandType"
  ]
}
```

I then go to [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and create a POJO, selecting "Gson" as the annotation style since it seems the thing to do. I press Preview and get a class that doesn't contain those enum values;

```
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class CommandType {

@Expose
private String type;
@SerializedName("enum")
@Expose
private List<String> _enum = new ArrayList<String>();

/**
* 
* @return
* The type
*/
public String getType() {
return type;
}

/**
* 
* @param type
* The type
*/
public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The _enum
*/
public List<String> getEnum() {
return _enum;
}

/**
* 
* @param _enum
* The enum
*/
public void setEnum(List<String> _enum) {
this._enum = _enum;
}

}
```

Unsurprisingly, if I go on to try and deserialize something using this in an Android app, I get an object that just has default values for the fields. Since there's obvious problems at this stage I've not included details of the Android side.

Aside from the missing enum values, there's no property in the POJO called "CommandType." The class itself has taken that name, the original name being lost in schema generation.

If I try the generated schema against [jsonschemavalidator](http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) I get the error

```
  Found 1 error(s)
  Message: Required properties are missing from object: CommandType.
  Schema path: #/required
```

So it seems I'm using Json.NET wrongly. However my usage seems pretty simple; I want enum strings rather than an int to make the eventual protocol robust as things change, and I want a type indication so I can deserialise to the correct POJO on the Android side, since I'll be having several different classes for a multitype query/response protocol. Is there something obviously wrong in my attempt to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select JSON Schema rather than JSON as your Source type at http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Results:

```
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public static enum CommandType {

UNKNOWN("UNKNOWN"),
PING("PING"),
GET_TIMINGS("GET_TIMINGS"),
GET_EVENT_ID("GET_EVENT_ID"),
NEW_EVENT("NEW_EVENT"),
LOAD_PEOPLE("LOAD_PEOPLE"),
LOAD_TAGS("LOAD_TAGS"),
SET_LOCATION("SET_LOCATION");
private final String value;
...etc
```